# MPI result is different under Slurm and by using command

Tags: c++, mpi, slurm

I met an issue when run a MPI project by Slurm.

a1 is my executable file. 
It works well when I just run `mpiexec -np 4 ./a1`

But it can not work well when I run it under Slurm, and it looks like it stop in the middle:

This is the output by using `mpiexec -np 4 ./a1`,this is correct.

```
Processor1 will send and receive with processor0
Processor3 will send and receive with processor0
Processor0 will send and receive with processor1
Processor0 finished send and receive with processor1
Processor1 finished send and receive with processor0
Processor2 will send and receive with processor0
Processor1 will send and receive with processor2
Processor2 finished send and receive with processor0
Processor0 will send and receive with processor2
Processor0 finished send and receive with processor2
Processor0 will send and receive with processor3
Processor0 finished send and receive with processor3
Processor3 finished send and receive with processor0
Processor1 finished send and receive with processor2
Processor2 will send and receive with processor1
Processor2 finished send and receive with processor1
Processor0: I am very good, I save the hash in range 0 to 65
p: 4
Tp: 8.61754
Processor1 will send and receive with processor3
Processor3 will send and receive with processor1
Processor3 finished send and receive with processor1
Processor1 finished send and receive with processor3
Processor2 will send and receive with processor3
Processor1: I am very good, I save the hash in range 65 to 130
Processor2 finished send and receive with processor3
Processor3 will send and receive with processor2
Processor3 finished send and receive with processor2
Processor3: I am very good, I save the hash in range 195 to 260
Processor2: I am very good, I save the hash in range 130 to 195
```

And this is the output under Slurm, it does not return the entire result like using command.

```
Processor0 will send and receive with processor1
Processor2 will send and receive with processor0
Processor3 will send and receive with processor0
Processor1 will send and receive with processor0
Processor0 finished send and receive with processor1
Processor1 finished send and receive with processor0
Processor0 will send and receive with processor2
Processor0 finished send and receive with processor2
Processor2 finished send and receive with processor0
Processor1 will send and receive with processor2
Processor0 will send and receive with processor3
Processor2 will send and receive with processor1
Processor2 finished send and receive with processor1
Processor2 will send and receive with processor3
Processor1 finished send and receive with processor2
```

This is my Slurm.sh file: I think I made some mistake in it that the result is different from the command one, but I am not sure about this...

```
#!/bin/bash

####### select partition (check CCR documentation)
#SBATCH --partition=general-compute --qos=general-compute

####### set memory that nodes provide (check CCR documentation, e.g., 32GB)
#SBATCH --mem=64000

####### make sure no other jobs are assigned to your nodes
#SBATCH --exclusive

####### further customizations
#SBATCH --job-name="a1"
#SBATCH --output=%j.stdout
#SBATCH --error=%j.stderr
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=16
#SBATCH --time=12:00:00

mpiexec -np 4 ./a1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, come back to solve my question.
I made a silly mistake that I use a wrong slurm.sh for my mpi code. 
The correct slurm.sh is :

```
#!/bin/bash

####### select partition (check CCR documentation)
#SBATCH --partition=general-compute --qos=general-compute

####### set memory that nodes provide (check CCR documentation, e.g., 32GB)
#SBATCH --mem=32000

####### make sure no other jobs are assigned to your nodes
#SBATCH --exclusive

####### further customizations
#SBATCH --job-name="a1"
#SBATCH --output=%j.stdout
#SBATCH --error=%j.stderr
#SBATCH --nodes=4
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=12
#SBATCH --time=01:00:00

####### check modules to see which version of MPI is available
####### and use appropriate module if needed
module load intel-mpi/2018.3
export I_MPI_PMI_LIBRARY=/usr/lib64/libpmi.so

srun /.a1
```

I am so silly that's why I use Konan as a nickname... I hope I can become smart.